# Will Windows on the touch screen to emulate the MouseDown event by touching a finger?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, mouseevent, sensors

I am writing an application that needs to support the touch screen.
Now I debug the application using the mouse.
Advice please. Do I need to override all messages like `TouchDown` to respond to touch.
Or enough for me to handle `MouseDown`?
Will Windows on the touch screen to emulate the `MouseDown` event by touching a finger?

p.s Unfortunately I do not have now any touchscreen device to test.

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows 8

Answer (score 2):

My experience working on Win7 x64 w/ a touch screen is that touch screen does emulate the MouseDown event.